# Regular expression ignoring text

Tags: regex

I am not sure how to approach this. If someone could help that would be great.

I need to match for a parser
Version 2.5 (Build 4612)

but I need it to be Version 2.5 combined with the build, so it will look look like 2.5.4612, in the match. In other words it needs to omit  (Build

thanks in advance.

Comment: what language are you using and what have you tried?

Answer (score 3):

A regex will always match the text as it is, but you're free to ignore parts of the match later. For example

```
(Version \d+\.\d+) \(Build (\d+)
```

will match `Version 2.5` in group 1 and `4612` in group 2, so if your later combine the two groups with a `.`, you get the desired result.

Answer (score 0):

```
([0-9.]+).*?([0-9.]+)
```

would work assuming 1 per line

back reference \1.\2  would show 2.5.4612 in your case

this way helps that you you dont have to have version or build exactly as they are in your example, Its a little more general